# retrieve lookup column twice with associated rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables.
First one

```
farmer_id         Farmer_name
   1               Raju
   2               Jay
   3               Ram
   5               Vinay
```

Second one

```
farmer_id      registered_farmer_id  Season
  1                  2               2014-15
  3                  5               2015-16
```

Table one is the look up table which looks for the name of the farmer. Table two has two columns namely farmer_id and registered-farmer_id those look up for the same table. i.e table 1. What I need is

```
Farmer_id    farmer_name    Registered_farmer_id   Registered_farmer_name
  1           Raju                  2                   Jay
  3           Ram                   5                   Vinay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T2.farmer_id, T1.farmer_name, T2.registered_farmer_id, T3.farmer_name
FROM TABLE2 T2 
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1
ON T2.farmer_id = T1.farmer_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T3
ON T2.registered_farmer_id = T3.farmer_id;
```

With TABLE1 the name of table 1 and TABLE2 the name of table 2.

Comment: Thank you buddy @user3331966

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL 2005+, you can use [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT A.farmer_id, A.Farmer_name, B.farmer_id, B.Farmer_name
FROM (
      SELECT T1.farmer_id, T2.Farmer_name, T3.Registered_farmer_id
      FROM Table1 T1
         INNER JOIN Table T2
            ON T1.farmer_id = T2.farmer_id
     ) AS A
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT farmer_id, Farmer_name
      FROM Table1
      WHERE farmer_id = A.Registered_farmer_id
      ) AS B
```

In Oracle, you use INNER JOIN instead:

```
SELECT A.farmer_id, A.Farmer_name, B.farmer_id, B.Farmer_name
FROM (
      SELECT T1.farmer_id, T2.Farmer_name, T3.Registered_farmer_id
      FROM Table1 T1
         INNER JOIN Table T2
            ON T1.farmer_id = T2.farmer_id
     ) AS A
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT farmer_id, Farmer_name
      FROM Table1
      ) AS B
WHERE B.farmer_id = A.Registered_farmer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if your two tables are called from 2 different database tables; then you should change the second table's id with a different name and join both table.
and finally you can retrieve from the merged table.

Comment: But second table has two columns farmer_id which looks for actual farmer_name in first table as well as another column registered-farmer_id also looks the same first table for associated names. So the columns looks the same table (Second) to find associated names.

Comment: i think that is causing an ambiguous problem, if you want to show the id column in the retrieve page, then it should be unique, so i suggest change  the 2nd one's id field with a different name tag and merge them both.

Answer (score 0):

lets say your tables are called Table1(the lookup) and Table2

select t1.NAME fname, t2.NAME rfname 
    from Table1 t1, Table1 t2, Table2
    where t1.id = table1.ID and t2.id = table1.ID2
;